# Reorder PRODUCTS in categories Woo

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Greatings,

Is there a way to reorder Products in Categories (Not categories).

For example if i try by date reorder in categories date is not working only working in global shop page.

Maybe there is a way by plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Your prayers have been answered - https://wordpress.org/plugins/rearrange-woocommerce-products/

Thanks, Jason.